# Azure's new Deployment slot (preview) traffic % seems very confusing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have noted that in the new Deployment Slot (Preview), the traffic% is 100% for the production slot if one is on the production slot. If one enters a deployment slot, then the traffic% is then 100% for that deployment slot. Clearly one does not want any live traffic coming through on a deployment slot while one is checking it/ warming it up.

I typically just swap between staging slots and production so this traffic% facility is redundant for me.

How can one be sure that the deployment staging slot will not let in traffic when one is in that staging slot, when it seems to say 100% for traffic%.

Also a little concerned about this since the classic deployment slots is being retired in January 2019 which worked fine.

Any help gratefully received.

EDIT

In Production Slot
Click on "Deployment slots (Preview)"
Production slot is set to 100% traffic by default.

Now click on "Staging" Deployment slot from Production
Click on "Deployment slots (Preview)"
"Staging" Deployment slot is set to 100% traffic by default. This confuses me! However I may be missing something?

EDIT2:

Merging of the "Testing in Production" into the "Deployment Slot" feature can be dangerous as it is very easy to spread live traffic to a staging slot, when this is not desired. When the "Testing in Production" was seperate this was not an issue. Now that it is merged, it is. Perhaps some warning may be appropriate?

Comment: Not sure I'm following here. When you create a slot under the main app, it's automatically created with 0% of the app's traffic. This was the case in the old menu as it is now in the new one. I just ran a test to validate and my new slot is marked as 0% traffic. Are you saying your new slot is getting 100% when you create it?

Comment: Oded,thanks for the comment. It is when you select the deployment slot and go into it, so that you can set its application settings etc, and then click on Deployment Slots (Preview). You will see that the Slot that you are in now has 100% traffic and Production has 0%.

Comment: I have tried the mechanism since posting this question, and when one starts the slots, 100% traffic still goes to the Production slot. However it still seems really confusing and alarming !!

Comment: I have amended my question with further details under EDIT

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue now and can reproduce. I'm not sure this is the case on the backed but I will validate with our team.

Comment: Ok, so what I learned is the experience right now is as expected. The thing is that when you are in the slot view (after you click your slot name), the 100% means that 100% of the traffic hitting the url of the slot, will go to that slot. On the other hand, in the main app's menu, 100% to production means all user hitting the main app's url will go there. When you make a change to the traffic settings between the app and slot, you'll notice that in the slot view, you'll still see 100% to the slot.

Comment: There are improvements to this view and to the backend behavior coming in January though, to make this less confusing. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Oded, Thanks for this. Very useful. I think having this "Traffic%" facility in the deployment slot as well is really confusing and I am unsure of its value. I did wonder whether this was the reason however. If you wish to place an answer then I will mark it as such. Thank you again.

Comment: Great, thanks for surfacing your feedback, very valuable! As I said, the feedback is with the right engineering team in charge of this menu.

Answer (score 2):

A web app and a deployment slot are accessible through their respective URLs

For this example lets assume you have an app called "myapp" with a deployment slot called "stage"

In this case they would be accessible throught he follwoing URLS:

- myapp --> myapp.azurewebsites.net
- stage --> myapp-stage.azurewebsites.net

if you have not configured TIP rules then 100% of traffic going to myapp.azurewebsites.net will be routed there and no traffic will be routed from that URL to the deployment slot.

The changes that were made to integrate TIP + Deployment slots UX is to make this features more useful and in context (you can't use TIP without slots).

Unintentional changes to the TIP values require you to save your changes and are not applied until saved.

The other thing to note is that wile not all users will chose to use TIP, this simplified view gives TIP users a better way to interact with the rules and deployment slots and it makes TIP feature more discover-able (TIP has been a supported feature for many years, however it has suffered from low discoverability due to it being lost in the UX menu)

Comment: TIP is here referring to Testing in Production (TiP), more information available in https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/07/07/zero_to_hero_pt3.html#testing-in-production